# What is the closed-form solution for the PV of the following series?

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, quantitative

I have the following exercise, where a closed-form solution is needed for the PV of the cash flows.  [image]

The teacher's solution is the following:
[image]

But I fail to understand how exactly we get to it in the 1st place. A detailed, step-by-step solution would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Hi, this is effectively no quantfinance question. You might try to get help from the math community, tho?